# Angular did not work on all browser.It only work on chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, browser

I deploy a angular project using node api that send json data.But it only work fine on chrome.On other browser,it did not work and did not get json data from node. On chrome,it work.What should I do to work on all browser including android browser?Please give me advice.Thank You.

Comment: You better show some code

Comment: There's no way anyone can help you without seeing relevant code (probably the client-side code that doesn't work in the Android browser).

Answer (score 0):

see you have to write codes for other browsers 
for example:
-moz- ..... write this code before your code then you'll be able to see output in mozila firefox

-webkit- .... and this for chrome
and there are vareity of codes for other browsers